# Order by before group by not giving real results

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hello i tried this query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            specials_companies_mails 
        WHERE 
            `toId` = 1 && parentId <> 0 
        ORDER BY 
            specials_companies_mails.mailId DESC
    ) AS b 
GROUP BY 
    b.parentId
```

i have two rows in the table:

```
mailID           subject        toId        parentId
3                test1          1           2
4                test2          1           2
```

and the result after the query:

```
mailID           subject        toId        parentId
3                test1          1           2
```

its mean that

```
ORDER BY specials_companies_mails.mailId DESC
```

not working... its give me mailId 3 and not 4...

what to do?

tnx a lot

Comment: what is this query for??what do you want to retrieve?

Comment: you are using `GROUP BY   b.parentId` thats why there is only one record.

Comment: @B.Desai i want one record but the second one ... (the most newest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` doesn't care about the `ORDER BY`. The selected record will be totally non deterministic.

What you can do is find latest `mainId` for each `parentId` like this:

```
select a.* 
from specials_companies_mails AS a
left join specials_companies_mails AS b
    on  a.parentId = b.parentId
    and a.mailID < b.mailID
    and b.toId = 1 
    and b.parentId <> 0
WHERE b.parentId is null
    and a.toId = 1 
    and a.parentId <> 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT `a`.* FROM `specials_companies_mails` AS `a`
LEFT JOIN `specials_companies_mails` AS `b` ON
    `a`.`mailID` =  `b`.`mailID` AND
    `a`.`mailID` <  `b`.`mailID`
WHERE `b`.`mailID` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

group by doesn't care if you have ordered records before or not. It gets information from first record saved in database, always. This is a painful thing that every developer faces, so don't worry.

You can solve the issue on a couple of ways.

1. Split this into 2 separate queries - first query will order by and second will show you selected fields `WHERE id IN (...)`
2. Join table `specials_companies_mails` with `specials_companies_mails`, but this won't be good for performance and is quite long.
3. Don't group and write a part of code responsible for parsing data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only latest record then try this:(I think you not need group by clause )

```
SELECT * 
        FROM 
            specials_companies_mails 
        WHERE 
            `toId` = 1 && parentId <> 0 
        ORDER BY 
            mailId DESC
       LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I want the newest one after group by... i gave a example of 2 rows but i have a lot of rows...